MediaDRM with Emulator
I use MediaDRM with WideVine to create uniq array of device like this:
val WIDEVINE_UUID = UUID.fromString("edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed")
val mediaDrm = MediaDrm(WIDEVINE_UUID)
val drumID = mediaDrm.getPropertyByteArray("deviceUniqueId")

After this I started this code in Android Studio with Studios Pixel Emulator, I took what was expected, but after this I started this code in Genymotion Emulator and I took exception.
android.media.UnsupportedSchemeException: Failed to instantiate drm object: NO_INIT 
============================ Beginning of DRM Plugin Log ==============================
06-13 06:41:24.075 I found instance=clearkey version=android.hardware.drm@1.4::IDrmFactory
06-13 06:41:24.075 I found instance=default version=android.hardware.drm@1.0::IDrmFactory
06-13 06:41:24.076 E uuid=[edef8ba979d64ace a3c827dcd51d21ed] No supported hal instance found
06-13 06:41:24.077 E uuid=[edef8ba979d64ace a3c827dcd51d21ed] No supported hal instance found
============================== End of DRM Plugin Log ==============================
at android.media.MediaDrm.native_setup(Native Method)

I think genymotions emulator doesn't support this feature. If I'm wrong, tell me where I'm wrong.

Similar: DRM support for BlueStacks
